# Get a string representation of a single byte from QByteArray?

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a QByteArray i create manually:

```
QByteArray hexArray(QByteArray::fromHex("495676"));
```

If this was encoded ASCII it would be "IVv".
If I want to get a single byte of data from that array.
I can do that like this:

```
qDebug() << messageToBeSent_raw[0];
```

However, that outputs `I`, which is correct but I would like to get `49`. What I'm looking for is an equivalent of the `QByteArray::toHex()` just for a single byte. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: just cast it: `qDebug() << (int)messageToBeSent_raw[0];` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`QString::number`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#number).

```
qDebug() << QString::number(hexArray[0], 16);
```

Comment: or QByteArray::number(), in case you want to stay in QByteArray space

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Do you know how to get a representation with the zero in front. Example. `QString::number(QByteArray::fromHex("0102")[0], 16)` gives "1" and I need "01".